# Manipulating Pixels(Drawing) in Java

Tags: java

This is not a typical "what library do i use?" or "is there an API for that". Using lines of code I create not implementing them through a library of sorts. Is there any documentation on how to actually create a window, and within that window draw a line from pixels?

I just want to understand how its done, and not learn through a library which does it for me.

Previously tried:
JavaFx
Swing

Comment: I basically asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553845/id-like-to-draw-pixels-on-a-window-with-mouse-input)

Comment: @SeanPedersen Im not trying to draw it with a mouse, im trying to simply put the shape on the screen with no use of API or framework or library

Comment: You want to "create a window, and within that window draw a line from pixels". That sounds a lot like "draw pixes on a window".

Comment: You can also check out [Drawing Geometric Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html).

Comment: You could try looking at the source code for Swing to see how it's done. I'd just stick to using libraries, though, as it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw a line in a window, you'll ultimately have to create a BufferedImage, set pixels in that BufferedImage according to some drawing algorithm (like Bresenham's), then put the BufferedImage in the window.