# Using Key Bindings to move Images

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am trying to create a Tanks game but am still learning how to do graphics programming in Java. I had initially tried moving one of two images (which one depends on which player is going) with KeyListeners. I was told that Key Bindings might be a more effective way of going about this. Here is some of my code:

```
    public class FrameMain extends JFrame{
    ...
        public FrameMain(){

           this.addBindings();
```

The addBindings() method:

```
    protected void addBindings() {
       InputMap inputMap = pnlPlay.getInputMap();       

       KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Event.KEY_PRESS);
       inputMap.put(key, pnlPlay.pnlGame.MoveTank(2, pnlPlay.nPlayer));

       key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Event.KEY_PRESS);   
       inputMap.put(key, pnlPlay.pnlGame.MoveTank(-2, pnlPlay.nPlayer));
}
```

The MoveTank method:

```
    public int MoveTank(int xChange, int nPlayer){

       System.out.println("move "+nPlayer);

       if(nPlayer==0){
           tank1.x+=xChange;
       }else tank2.x+=xChange;

       repaint();
       return 1;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I press either the right or left arrow key, I am not getting any kind of response. It should be printing "move #" but it's not. If anyone knows what I have done wrong or could point me in the direction of some code that does the same thing I would appreciate it. I learn best from seeing the code in working order and then playing around with it.

Comment: Methods in Java should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: You can check out my example posted here: [Swing Timer and Key Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things with this code:

- I do not see anything about the action map. The input map maps a key to an action identifier, and the action map is the link between the identifier and the actual action. So you normally have code like

  ```
  InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap( );
  ActionMap actionMap =  component.getActionMap();
  Action actionToTrigger = ...;
  actionMap.put( "myAction", actionToTrigger );
  inputMap.put( key, "myAction" );
  ```
- If putting your action in the action map with the correct identifier and it still does not work, you might have been using the wrong input map. There are 3 different input maps as explained in the Swing keybindings guide. Try with the others

Perhaps you should consult the [Swing keybindings tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) again as it explains all this in more detail + contains code examples