# How to create an interactive animation?

Tags: java, swing, animation, keylistener, key-bindings

So my teacher wants me to make an interactive animation. The problem is that he didn't tell the class how to do it. (It's an online course). The gist is that he wants me to make a graphic that can be controlled with the keyboard. I've looked around online but apparently I haven't been asking the right questions because for some reason I'm coming up empty.

Anyways. I have three code files. Zorx1, Zorx2, and Zorx3 which are just the same alien with minor differences in color, which was given by the teacher.

```
// The Zorx alien object
import java.awt.*;
public class Zorx1
{
/* the fields of the object defined here as static to make the 
interface as simple as possible to start*/
static int x = 100, y = 100;
static int size = 50;
static Color clr = Color.red;
static boolean showing = false;
// paints Zorx on the screen Note this method is not part of Interface
static void paint (Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor (clr);
    g.fillRect (x, y, size / 4, size);
    g.setColor (Color.black);
    g.drawLine (x-3,y-2,x-1,y+size/8);//These four lines will add fangs to this guy. Nasty!
    g.drawLine (x-2,y-2,x-1,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x+3,y-2,x+5,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x+2,y-2,x+4,y+size/8);
    g.setColor (clr);
    g.fillOval (x - (3 * size / 8), y - (size / 2), size, size / 2);
    g.drawLine (x - 3 * size / 8, y + size, x - 3 * size / 8 + size, y + size);
    g.drawLine (x, y + size / 2, x - size, y);
    g.drawLine (x - size, y, x - size, y - size / 4);
    g.drawOval (x - size - size / 8, y - size / 4 - size / 8, size / 8, size / 8);
    g.setXORMode (Color.black); //Makes his eyes black. Sinister
    g.fillOval (x - size / 4, y - size / 3, size / 12, size / 12);
    g.fillOval (x + size / 4, y - size / 3, size / 12, size / 12);
    g.fillOval (x - size / 1000, y - size / 4, size / 12, size / 12); //adds a third eye to our alien. Spooooooooky.
    g.setPaintMode ();
} // end of paint method

// Show the Zorx alien. The show method is part of the interface.
public static void show (Graphics g)
{
    paint (g);
    showing = true;
} // end of show method

// Erase Zorx from the screen. The erase method
// is not part of the interface.
static void erase (Graphics g, Color backgroundColor)
{
    g.setColor (backgroundColor);
    g.fillRect (x, y, size / 4, size);
    g.fillOval (x - (3 * size / 8), y - (size / 2), size, size / 2);
    g.drawLine (x-3,y-2,x-1,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x-2,y-2,x-1,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x+3,y-2,x+5,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x+2,y-2,x+4,y+size/8);
    g.drawLine (x - 3 * size / 8, y + size, x - 3 * size / 8 + size, y + size);
    g.drawLine (x, y + size / 2, x - size, y);
    g.drawLine (x - size, y, x - size, y - size / 4);
    g.drawOval (x - size - size / 8, y - size / 4 - size / 8, size / 8, size / 8);
    g.fillOval (x - size / 4, y - size / 3, size / 12, size / 12);
    g.fillOval (x + size / 4, y - size / 3, size / 12, size / 12);
} // end of erase method

// Hide Zorx The hide method is part of the interface.
public static void hide (Graphics g, Color backgroundColor)
{
    erase (g, backgroundColor);
    showing = false;
} // end of hide method

// Move Zorx from one location to another. The move method
// is part of the interface.
public static void move (int newX, int newY, Graphics g, Color backgroundColor)
{
    if (showing)
    {
        erase (g, backgroundColor);
    }
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
    if (showing)
    {
        show (g);
    }
} // end of move method
} // end of Zorx Class
```

The alien object has all the methods and everything necessary to move the object around, while the Animation is supposed to control all of this.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Animation extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    public Animation (Graphics g)
    {
        Zorx1.show(g);
        Zorx2.show(g);
        Zorx3.show(g);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Animation application = new Animation(g);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
    public int x=100;
    public int y=100;
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) //I can't seem to get this thing to animate through this so this is just left blank for the sake of necessity.
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            break;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            left(g);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            right(g);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            up(g);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            down(g);
        }
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
            // If you hit escape you will exit the animation
        }
    }
    public void left (Graphics g)
    {
        x=x-10;
        Zorx1.move (x,y, g, getBackground ());
        Zorx2.move (x,y+50,g,getBackground());
        Zorx3.move (x,y+100,g,getBackground());
    }
    public void right (Graphics g)
    {
        x=x+10;
        Zorx1.move (x,y,g,getBackground());
        Zorx2.move (x,y+50,g,getBackground());
        Zorx3.move (x,y+100,g,getBackground());
    }
    public void up(Graphics g)
    {
        y=y-10;
        Zorx1.move (x,y,g,getBackground());
        Zorx2.move (x,y+50,g,getBackground());
        Zorx3.move (x,y+100,g,getBackground());
    }
    public void down(Graphics g)
    {
        y=y+10;
        Zorx1.move (x,y,g,getBackground());
        Zorx2.move (x,y+50,g,getBackground());
        Zorx3.move (x,y+100,g,getBackground());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the code above doesn't work, but that's probably because I have no idea what the heck I'm supposed to be doing.

I figured out what was causing the overriding static method problem. I had added extends JFrame to the zorx1.java thing and that had caused a conflict with the paint (Graphics g) part. So I just renamed it into make (Graphics g). Hopefully that will not cause complications.

I think I should be able to move the keyboard interactive part into a different class (I hope) but I have a problem with that too.

```
public class Animation extends JFrame
{
    public int x=100;
    public int y=100;
    public Animation (Graphics g)
    {

        Zorx1.show(g);
        Zorx2.show(g);
        Zorx3.show(g);
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Animation application = new Animation (g);
    }
```

new Animation (g); can't find the symbol g. And I can't add it in anywhere because it will cause a problem. How can I make it recognize the symbol, or have I never needed it in the first place?

```
    public Animation ()
    {
        repaint();
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Zorx1.show(g);
        Zorx2.show(g);
        Zorx3.show(g);
    }
```

Okay, I think I got it, but super.paintComponent(g); is returning an error in which it says: "cannot find symbol - method paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)."

Fixed it. Finally.

Comment: Please re-read my posts and the tutorials. I have told you several times what type of class this method must reside in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Read the Swing graphics tutorials to see the best ways to draw with Swing. You appear to be making a lot of your graphics code up, and this simply won't work. Go to the source and learn to do it right. Google will help you find these tutorials.
- For instance, you shouldn't draw directly on the JFrame.
- Instead draw in a JComponent's (such as a JPanel's) `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Avoid using KeyListeners but instead use Key Bindings.
- Use a Swing Timer for your animation loop.
- You can find many examples of this (including mine) on this site with a little searching. For example please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444).

Edit: your latest code attempts to do animation in a JFrame constructor which isn't going to work. As noted above, the GUI drawing must be in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` override method of a JPanel or JComponent. Here you can use the Graphics object that the JVM passes into the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Comment: If this is about how the zorx1.java file is drawn with all those x's and y's all ridiculously, I received that code from the teacher and I'm guessing he made it hard to read like that on purpose. I suppose I should be rephrasing my question, but my problem is that I don't know how to use KeyListeners, bindings, or whatever and the examples that are usually around keep their graphics in the same class as the keylisteners and whatnot, which is something the teacher ordered us not to do. That is to say, we need to keep the aliens in separate .java files.

Comment: @JackSnyder: I'm not sure which code is yours and which is your teachers, but the ugly guessing code I'm mainly talking about is that which is in your 2nd class, your Animation class which looks to be all over the place. If this is your teacher's code, quit the class. Regarding separation, I'd recommend that you keep your Key Bindings with your drawing class to start with, and then once you get it working, refactor the code to separate them into separate classes. This is called the [Tracer Bullet](http://www.artima.com/intv/tracer.html) method of programming.

Comment: Well, you were right about the ugly guessing part, because I really have no idea what I'm doing when it came down to basically anything there. The only things I knew what I was doing when I typed it in was the Zorx1.show(g); part. After that everything pretty much went to the wind. Anyways, when talking about the separation thing, I really have no idea how to do it because I don't know how to do this key bindings (or listening) thing so I'm already stuck on step 1.

Comment: @JackSnyder: that is why God invented tutorials, and it is these which you should seek out, them and the examples to be found on this site such as the link that I placed in my last bullet.

Comment: Okay, so I think I'm somewhere right now. I add a panel to the frame, then add the KeyListener to that Panel alongside drawing the alien in it? Am I right so far?

Comment: @JackSnyder: that sounds like a very good plan except for the KeyListener part. For my money, I'd use key binding with the JPanel. If you use binding, you don't have to worry so much about the bound component having the focus.

Comment: I have no idea what a Keybinding is so I'm sticking with KeyListener for now because it's more familiar and the deadline is soon so I don't know if I can afford to learn another new thing right now. But I also ran into a problem, I can't compile and the error it says: paint (java.awt.Graphics) in Zorx1 cannot override paint(java.awt.Graphics in java.awt.Window Overriding method is static. and when I search I get a bunch of unrelated stuff. On a side note, should I start editing my answer as my problem changes? I don't think it would be a good idea to just ask a new question...

Comment: @JackSnyder: yes, you can edit your original question, but don't remove any existing code or question text unless it is to improve readability. Add any new code and question text to the bottom of your original question. Let's see what code currently causes the exception.

Comment: So I create a new method name paintComponent (Graphics g), then I... load (for lack of a better word to my knowledge) Zorx1 into then I make Zorx1.show(g);? Or is that not right?

Comment: Edited. These extras letters are to fill out letter count.