# Move a rectangle in a JPanel using the keys

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, move, paintcomponent

I have a class called "DisplayPanel" (which extends JPanel) and I draw a square there that comes from a class called "Square" (which extends JComponent).  How to move a rectangle in a JPanel using the keys?

The Square class has the usual painting method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Dimension dimension = getSize();
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics2D.fill(squarishThing); 
}
```

And the "squarishThing" is a normal rectangle:

```
Rectangle squarishThing = new Rectangle (0, 0, 50, 50);
```

The thing is: Unlike "game libraries", trying to do such a thing "manually" is quite confusing. I don't know where the "while loop" goes. I tried to put a KeyListener in the DisplayPanel and I failed miserably to update the rectangle. There's no loop, and I can't repaint the rectangle because the method paintComponent takes that unpleasant argument. OBS: Everytime I try to insert a loop, the software crashes dramatically, so I gave up of doing so.

What can I do to repaint the object according to inputs?

Comment: Look at using Key Bindings. For example please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444).

Comment: Is this for a game? If it is, you'll need a loop. And what do you mean 'crashes dramatically'? Loops aren't dynamite.

Comment: A Swing Timer could work for a simple game loop.

Answer (score 2):

*can't repaint the rectangle because the method paintComponent takes that unpleasant argument*.
 Never ever call paintComponent, instead use repaint().

Using KeyBindings simply update "squarishThing" to the appropriate value, then call repaint().