# Implementing a CTRL_MASK in Swing Action Event

Tags: java, swing, java-7, keyevent, actionevent

I must be missing something here, but I can't figure out why the `InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK` nor `InputEvent.CTRL_MASK` work?

What I am trying to do is implement a way for Ctrl-C to issue a command in a Swing GUI. I am using the following code:

```
  myTextArea.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(
      KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) 'c', /***/InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK/***/), "ctrl");
  myTextArea.getActionMap().put("ctrl", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("test");
    }
  });
```

Notice the `InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK`. When I keep it in there, the action never gets performed. When I comment it out, the action works (but I am only pressing the lower-case 'c' button. Not ctrl.

Am I missing something on how to really use the CTRL_MASK for swing key events?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something on how to really use the CTRL_MASK for swing
>   key events?

- you have to put this paramater to the `InputMap`

e.g. `inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(myKey, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), someName);`

Comment: OP's calling `getInputMap(...).put(KeyStroke, String)` in the example.

Comment: @Eric S nothing beter as  [answers about by top Swing Gurus here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887296/how-to-make-an-image-move-while-listening-to-a-keypress-in-java)

Comment: Oops; I meant `...put(char, int)` - what I was saying is that it looks to me like OP is calling the method you're telling him to, with the modifier in the right place; the `put()` call is just chained after a `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks mostly right to me, but try

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
```

instead of

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) 'c', InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
```

ie, don't rely on the `int` interpretations of `char` values to pass your key code; use the "virtual keyboard" constants Java provides.

Comment: I was doing that before, but it was using only capital 'C'