# Timer to repeat SOMETHING until SOMETHING_ELSE

Tags: java, swing, timer

The thing that I need is: do X++ and Y++ of an JButton until "x++ == Z and y++ == W" resulting into an movement of the button...

as far as ive got, first i need to get the coords of the button:

```
final int locXbtnTrapMe = igu.btnTrapMe.getX();
final int locYbtnTrapMe = igu.btnTrapMe.getY();
```

then specify the "Z" and "W" which are random limits as next:

```
int widthTrapMe = igu.btnTrapMe.getWidth();
int heightTrapMe = igu.btnTrapMe.getHeight();           
final int randX = random.nextInt(widthMainPanel-widthTrapMe);
final int randY = random.nextInt(heightMainPanel-heightTrapMe);
```

i specified those randoms like that so that the button doesnt go out of the main pannel... (thing i want)

Now the question: How can i do a ++ every 200ms for both locXbtnTrapMe and locYbtnTrapMe until the randX and randY get reached?

I need a smooth movement of the button from a point to another, not jumps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the question: How can i do a ++ every 200ms for both locXbtnTrapMe and locYbtnTrapMe until the randX and randY get reached?

Use a Swing Timer, and in the Timer's ActionListener's actionPerformed method, test the state of your watched fields, and increment them if below the maximum. Then make sure to call `stop()` on your Timer when the maximum has been reached.

Some decent links to help you out:

- [Java Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [One useful StackOverflow question re animation with Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887296/how-to-make-an-image-move-while-listening-to-a-keypress-in-java). There are many more if you look for them.