# My repaint in JFrame is not working

Tags: java, swing, draw, keylistener, repaint

I have a problem with repaint in JFrame i used repaint() earlier when i was making an animation and everything worked

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            y -= 2;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            y += 2;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            x -= 2;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            x += 2;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}

    }
```

This is my draw class which if i run as an applet everything works but i don't want an applet

My frame class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame  {

    Draw d = new Draw();

    public Frame(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Game");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);

        f.add(d);
        f.addKeyListener(new Draw());
    }

}
```

and my Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame f = new Frame();

    }

}
```

The repaint() is the one not working i tested the key listener it works so why isn't the repaint() working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KeyListener *shouldn't* be working since a JComponent by default cannot get program focus, a necessary requirement for a KeyListener to work. One solution is to make it focusable via `setFocusable(true)` and then call `requestFocusInWindow()` on it. Better to use Key Bindings ([tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)). Note that you should be overriding paintComponent, not paint and you should not forget to call the super's method within your override.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444)

Edit: I'm wrong since a JFrame **can** get focus and you're adding the KeyListener to the JFrame. But your problem is that you are creating a **new Draw object** to do this, not to the original displayed Draw object. Your code would actually work if you use the same Draw object for both displaying the image and for KeyListener:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JComponent implements KeyListener {
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
      if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
         y -= 2;
      } else if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
         y += 2;
      } else if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
         x -= 2;
      } else if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
         x += 2;
      }

      repaint();
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Draw d = new Draw();
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Game");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(800, 600);
            f.setVisible(true);

            f.add(d);
            f.addKeyListener(d);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Safer though is to use Key Bindings.

Comment: Thanks man my all i had to do is in draw class make a constructor and do this   public Draw(){
  addKeyListener(this);
  setFocusable(true);
 }
  and remove from the frame class addKeyListener and it works setFocusable did it :D