# Getting TILDE event in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, tilde

I am emulating an Arabic keyboard and why they use the Tilde key for an alphabet, I don't know. Regardless, I have to make it work.

I am using the following key binding code to grab the ~ key, but it doesn't seem to register:

```
JButton key = new JButton();
key.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(DEAD_TILDE, "action");
key.getActionMap().put("action", new KeyAction(key));
```

I have looked online and can't find an explanation for this.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: depends of is is used with InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK or not

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: I'm (from my Slovak keyboard) using SHIFT(isDown()) + VK_DEAD_TILDE

Comment: I see. Is there anyway to use the VK_DEAD_TILDE by itself?

Comment: Can you please tell me the code that I should use?

Comment: you have to combine modifiers (SHIFT/CTRL/ALT) with KeyEvents if is used, otherwise, good one [inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), name);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/714968) by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels (as always)