# jLabel Icon Animation Glictching

Tags: java, animation, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to make the person walk but for some reason when I switch icons the label returns to it's default location for a split second then updates to the where I set the bounds. Extremely annoying, any help is much appreciated. Thank You.

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JLabel x = new JLabel("");

ImageIcon player1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing52\\src\\testing52\\Player1.png");
ImageIcon player2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing52\\src\\testing52\\Player2.png");

static int count;

Timer timer;

Main(){

    timer = new Timer(100,this);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusable(false);
    add(x);

    timer.start();
}

public static void main(String [] args){

    Main main = new Main();    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    count += 1;

    if(count == 10){
        x.setIcon(player1);
    }
    if(count == 20){
        x.setIcon(player2);
    }

    if(count == 30){           
        count = 0;   
    }

    x.setBounds(0, 0,60,60);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setBounds(...)` call only works when the layout used is `null`. Having said that, **don't** use null layouts (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)), but instead use proper layout managers and component positioning.

Comment: Even when the Layout is set to null it still does the same thing

Comment: @KyleLongrich How did you set the layout to null?

Comment: inside Main(){} before i added it to the frame. "x.setLayout(null);"

Comment: @KyleLongrich It's not x's layout, it's the frame's layout.

Comment: @KyleLongrich: again, don't use null layouts. What positioning are you trying to achieve? A centering of the image? Also read up on the layout managers since you've much to learn about them -- including that it's the layout manager of the container that matters, not the component.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would say, don't use null layouts, unless a null layout is what you want. "Don't use such-and-such" is almost always dogma.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm just trying to make an icon that moves around the frame with a Key Listener. I'm not sure what positioning you would call that.

Comment: @immibis: agree, but that's why we need to see what he's trying to achieve. GUI's get so wonky if you use null layouts, and usually it's used as a beginner's crutch by folks who simply don't know how to use layout managers.

Comment: @KyleLongrich: OK that might be an indication for using null layouts, one of the few. And don't use KeyListeners for this but rather Key Bindings (Google the tutorial).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay will look into it. Thank You so much.

Comment: @KyleLongrich: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444)