# How to move the frog on Java Frogger game

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm developing a java Frogger game for a school project and now I'm adding the animations.
To do it, I've searched ideas on stack overflow, and I've found this post [How to make an image move while listening to a keypress in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887296/how-to-make-an-image-move-while-listening-to-a-keypress-in-java/6887628#6887628)
Following this example, I've created this code.

I would like to move the frog on a single press of the buttons, and to move it fluidly when the user keeps pressed the button.
With this code, on a single press, the frame of the frog's movement appears late; instead when I keep pressed the button, only the static frame is shown.

This is the Sprites that I've used.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKUIS.gif)

I try to fix it, but don't understand where is the problem. I've already searched other posts to find a solution, but I didn't find it.

---

I'm trying to fix it with your advice. Now it seems to work, but I've noticed a strange behaviour. If I press quickly one of the buttons, the program shows only the standing frame; I've added to my code some lines to debug it, and the movingIndex that should be equal to 1 after the user presses the button, turns to 0 creating this strange phenomenon.
This is the new code, I've created a MRE that can be tested creating a folder called "images" that contains the file upward.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Mcve3 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 640;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 150; //50;

    private int spriteX = 400;
    private int spriteY = 320;
    private SpriteDirection spriteDirection = SpriteDirection.RIGHT;
    private MySprite sprite = null;
    private Timer timer = null;

    public Mcve3() {
        try {
            sprite = new MySprite(spriteDirection, spriteX, spriteY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.FORWARD, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.AWAY, KeyEvent.VK_UP);

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection dir, int keyCode) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);

        inputMap.put(keyPressed, keyPressed.toString());
        inputMap.put(keyReleased, keyReleased.toString());

        actionMap.put(keyPressed.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, false));
        actionMap.put(keyReleased.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, true));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        sprite.draw(g);
    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private SpriteDirection dir;
        private boolean released;

        public MoveAction(SpriteDirection dir, boolean released) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.released = released;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (released) {
                sprite.setMoving(false);
            } else {
                sprite.setMoving(true);
                sprite.setDirection(dir);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sprite.tick2();
                repaint();
            }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Mcve3 mainPanel = new Mcve3();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class MySprite {
    
    private final int ZOOM_FACTOR = 50;
    
    //Frog's movement frames
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND = {1, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST = {19, 1, 16, 16};
    
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND = {73, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST = {91, 1, 16, 16};
    
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND = {37, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST = {55, 1, 16, 16};
    
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND = {109, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST = {127, 1, 16, 16};
    
    private static final int MAX_MOVING_INDEX = 2;
    private static final int DELTA = 50;
    private SpriteDirection direction;
    private Map<SpriteDirection, Image> standingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    private Map<SpriteDirection, List<Image>> movingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean moving = false;
    private int movingIndex = 0;
    private final static String PATH = "images/FroggerSpritesSenzaSfondo2.gif";
    private BufferedImage img;
    private boolean animationTerminated = true;

    public MySprite(SpriteDirection direction, int x, int y) throws IOException {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        createSprites();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Image img = null;
        
        if((moving && !animationTerminated) || (!moving && !animationTerminated)) {
            img = movingImgMap.get(direction).get(movingIndex);
        }
        else {
            img = standingImgMap.get(direction);
        }
        
        g.drawImage(img,
                x,
                y,
                x + ZOOM_FACTOR + img.getWidth(null),
                y + ZOOM_FACTOR + img.getHeight(null),
                0, 0, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),
                null);
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        if (moving) {
            switch (direction) {
            case RIGHT:
                x += DELTA;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                x -= DELTA;
                break;
            case FORWARD:
                y += DELTA;
                break;
            case AWAY:
                y -= DELTA;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void tick2() {
        if(moving) {
            if(movingIndex == 0 && animationTerminated ) { 
                tick();
                movingIndex++;
                movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
                animationTerminated = false;
            }
            else { 
                tick();
                movingIndex++;
                movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
                animationTerminated = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!animationTerminated) { 
                tick();
            }
            movingIndex++;
            movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
            if(movingIndex == 0) { 
                animationTerminated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void createSprites() throws IOException {
        
        loadImage(PATH);
        
        SpriteDirection dir = SpriteDirection.LEFT;
        List<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir, imgList);
        Image[] leftSprites = this.getFrogMoveLeftSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir, leftSprites[0]);
        imgList.add(leftSprites[1]);
        imgList.add(leftSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir1 = SpriteDirection.RIGHT;
        List<Image> imgList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir1, imgList1);
        Image[] rightSprites = this.getFrogMoveRightSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir1, rightSprites[0]);
        imgList1.add(rightSprites[1]);
        imgList1.add(rightSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir2 = SpriteDirection.FORWARD;
        List<Image> imgList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir2, imgList2);
        Image[] downSprites = this.getFrogMoveDownSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir2, downSprites[0]);
        imgList2.add(downSprites[1]);
        imgList2.add(downSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir3 = SpriteDirection.AWAY;
        List<Image> imgList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir3, imgList3);
        Image[] upSprites = this.getFrogMoveUpSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir3, upSprites[0]);
        imgList3.add(upSprites[1]);
        imgList3.add(upSprites[0]);
  
    }

    public SpriteDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(SpriteDirection direction) {
        if (this.direction != direction) {
            setMoving(false);
        }
        this.direction = direction;

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return moving;
    }

    public void setMoving(boolean moving) {
        this.moving = moving;
        if (!moving) {
            movingIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    
    public int getMovingIndex() {
        return movingIndex;
    }

    public void setMovingIndex(int movingIndex) {
        this.movingIndex = movingIndex;
    }

    private void loadImage(String fileName) {
        this.img = null;
        try {
            this.img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveUpSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveUpFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveUpFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveUpFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveUpFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveDownSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveDownFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveDownFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveDownFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveDownFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveLeftSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveLeftFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveLeftFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveLeftFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveLeftFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveRightSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveRightFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveRightFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveRightFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveRightFrames;
    }
}

enum SpriteDirection {
    FORWARD, LEFT, AWAY, RIGHT
}
```

And this is a screenshot of the strange behaviour showed in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYD7O.png)

Sorry for the comments not in English

---

I've update the code, and now the frog is more responsive, but the animation is not still visible when the user click rapidly the button.
I've added 2 boolean variables (buttonPressed and buttonReleased) to check if the user has pressed and released the button between 2 updates.

This is the new code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Mcve3 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 640;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 150; //50;

    private int spriteX = 400;
    private int spriteY = 320;
    private SpriteDirection spriteDirection = SpriteDirection.RIGHT;
    private MySprite sprite = null;
    private Timer timer = null;

    public Mcve3() {
        try {
            sprite = new MySprite(spriteDirection, spriteX, spriteY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.FORWARD, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.AWAY, KeyEvent.VK_UP);

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection dir, int keyCode) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);

        inputMap.put(keyPressed, keyPressed.toString());
        inputMap.put(keyReleased, keyReleased.toString());

        actionMap.put(keyPressed.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, false));
        actionMap.put(keyReleased.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, true));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        sprite.draw(g);
    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private SpriteDirection dir;
        private boolean released;

        public MoveAction(SpriteDirection dir, boolean released) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.released = released;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (released) {
                sprite.buttonReleased = true;
                sprite.setMoving(false);
            } else {
                sprite.buttonPressed = true;
                sprite.setMoving(true);
                sprite.setDirection(dir);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                if(sprite.buttonPressed && sprite.buttonReleased) {
                    sprite.animationTerminated=false;
                }
                
                sprite.tick2();
                repaint();
                
                sprite.buttonPressed = false;
                sprite.buttonReleased = false;
            }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Mcve3 mainPanel = new Mcve3();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class MySprite {
    
    private final int ZOOM_FACTOR = 50;
    
    //Frog's movement frames
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND = {1, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST = {19, 1, 16, 16};    
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND = {73, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST = {91, 1, 16, 16};  
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND = {37, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST = {55, 1, 16, 16};  
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND = {109, 1, 16, 16};
    private final static int[] FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST = {127, 1, 16, 16};
    private static final int MAX_MOVING_INDEX = 2;
    private static final int DELTA = 50;
    private final static String PATH = "images/FroggerSpritesSenzaSfondo2.gif";

    private SpriteDirection direction;
    private Map<SpriteDirection, Image> standingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    private Map<SpriteDirection, List<Image>> movingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int movingIndex = 0;
    
    private BufferedImage img;
    
    private boolean moving = false;
    protected boolean animationTerminated = true;
    protected boolean buttonPressed;
    protected boolean buttonReleased;

    public MySprite(SpriteDirection direction, int x, int y) throws IOException {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        createSprites();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Image img = null;
     
        if((moving && !animationTerminated) || (!moving && !animationTerminated) || (!moving && (buttonPressed && buttonReleased))) {
            img = movingImgMap.get(direction).get(movingIndex);
        }
        else {
            img = standingImgMap.get(direction);
        }

        g.drawImage(img, x, y, x + ZOOM_FACTOR + img.getWidth(null), y + ZOOM_FACTOR + img.getHeight(null), 0, 0, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), null);
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        if (moving || (buttonPressed && buttonReleased)) {
            switch (direction) {
            case RIGHT:
                x += DELTA;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                x -= DELTA;
                break;
            case FORWARD:
                y += DELTA;
                break;
            case AWAY:
                y -= DELTA;
            }    
        }
    }
    
    public void tick2() {
        if(moving) {
            
            if(movingIndex == 0 && animationTerminated ) { 
                tick();
                movingIndex++;
                movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
                animationTerminated = false;
            }
            else {
                tick();
                movingIndex++;
                movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
                animationTerminated = false;
            }
        }
        else if(buttonPressed && buttonReleased) {
            if(!animationTerminated) { 
                tick();
            }
            movingIndex++;
            movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
            if(movingIndex == 0) { 
                animationTerminated = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!animationTerminated) { 
                tick();
            }
            movingIndex++;
            movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
            if(movingIndex == 0) {
                animationTerminated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void createSprites() throws IOException {
        
        loadImage(PATH);
        
        SpriteDirection dir = SpriteDirection.LEFT;
        List<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir, imgList);
        Image[] leftSprites = this.getFrogMoveLeftSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir, leftSprites[0]);
        imgList.add(leftSprites[1]);
        imgList.add(leftSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir1 = SpriteDirection.RIGHT;
        List<Image> imgList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir1, imgList1);
        Image[] rightSprites = this.getFrogMoveRightSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir1, rightSprites[0]);
        imgList1.add(rightSprites[1]);
        imgList1.add(rightSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir2 = SpriteDirection.FORWARD;
        List<Image> imgList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir2, imgList2);
        Image[] downSprites = this.getFrogMoveDownSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir2, downSprites[0]);
        imgList2.add(downSprites[1]);
        imgList2.add(downSprites[0]);
        
        SpriteDirection dir3 = SpriteDirection.AWAY;
        List<Image> imgList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        movingImgMap.put(dir3, imgList3);
        Image[] upSprites = this.getFrogMoveUpSprites();
        standingImgMap.put(dir3, upSprites[0]);
        imgList3.add(upSprites[1]);
        imgList3.add(upSprites[0]);
  
    }

    public SpriteDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(SpriteDirection direction) {
        if (this.direction != direction) {
            setMoving(false);
        }
        this.direction = direction;

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return moving;
    }

    public void setMoving(boolean moving) {
        this.moving = moving;
        if (!moving) {
            movingIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    
    public int getMovingIndex() {
        return movingIndex;
    }

    public void setMovingIndex(int movingIndex) {
        this.movingIndex = movingIndex;
    }

    private void loadImage(String fileName) {
        this.img = null;
        try {
            this.img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveUpSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveUpFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveUpFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_UP_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveUpFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_UP_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveUpFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveDownSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveDownFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveDownFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveDownFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_DOWN_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveDownFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveLeftSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveLeftFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveLeftFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveLeftFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_LEFT_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveLeftFrames;
    }
    
    public Image[] getFrogMoveRightSprites() {
        loadImage(PATH); 
        Image[] frogMoveRightFrames = new Image[2];
        
        frogMoveRightFrames[0] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[0], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[1], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[2], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_STAND[3]);
        frogMoveRightFrames[1] = img.getSubimage(FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[0], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[1], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[2], FROG_MOVE_RIGHT_FIRST[3]);
    
        return frogMoveRightFrames;
    }
}

enum SpriteDirection {
    FORWARD, LEFT, AWAY, RIGHT
}
```

Comment: Detect when the key is down and put it into a map. When you release the key, remove it from the map. Each time the update/render is called, check to see if the key is active. If the key state did not change, continue to cycle through the active keyframes for the current direction. There should only ever be one active sprite sequence for a given direction. There is typically an idle, walking, or running animation (in each direction) in most top-down games.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I thought to this solution but if it continue to cycle, the program will display continuously only the movement frame, and the animation is not fluid. Considering that the animation is composed of 2 frames, a stationary one and a moving one, I would like to display all of them in sequence when the user keeps the button pressed.

Comment: @ScottHunter I would like to move the frog on a single press of the buttons, and to move it fluidly when the user keeps pressed the button. With this code, on a single press, the frame of the frog's movement appears late; instead when I keep pressed the button, only the static frame is shown.

Comment: Remove `movingIndex++;` from your draw method.  State should be changed in your tick() method only.  **Programmers don’t control when paintComponent is invoked.**  Painting is done by the system, whenever it has a reason to keep a window up to date.  Many many system conditions can cause it to happen.  Calling `repaint()` is a request to the system to paint as soon as possible, nothing more.

Comment: @VGR but removing movingIndex and the following commands, if I release the button, the variable moving will be false, so the method tick() will not be invoked. In this way, the animation can't be completed and the program will show continuously only the movement frame

Comment: *but removing movingIndex...* - then you need to restructure your code. The key point is that any painting method should only paint the current state of the component. It should NOT change the state of the component. The Timer is used for the animation. Therefore when the Timer fires you need to modify the state and repaint the component. *if I release the button* - then maybe you need to add more logic to the release button to make sure the state is what you expect.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It sounds like, in your current code you're checking the keys at each step in your update loop. So if you press and release before a step happens, then the jump doesn't happen. It's hard to say, you have so much code there.

Comment: @matt thanks for the comment, if this is the problem, how do you think I can solve it?

Comment: @Daniele *if* it's the problem, you would need to check if removing the key should cancel it. When a key press happens, set flag then clear that flag with the update happens. Then you can tell if a key press has happened since the last update.