# Browsing JButtons with Arrow Keys

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keyboard, jbutton

I've made a `JButton` array, which represent cards, there are 16 of them, 4 by 4.
How can I browse among the `JButton` with the arrows on keyboard instead of the mouse, and how can I "click" on `JButton` by pressing ENTER instead of mouseclicking? Maybe there is another way of doing this instead of using `JButton`s?

Best regards!

Comment: By default, all buttons can be clicked with <space>.  Also you can navigate between buttons with <tab> and <shift-tab>, but you'll just be able to go right until a line of four and then you'll go to the next line of four.

Comment: Actually, as I learned below... depending on your Swing look-and-feel sometimes <enter> is the default key that activates a button instead of <space>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a solution that will allow you to navigate buttons with the arrow keys and activate them with space and enter.

Below is all of the code.  No comments are provided, so let me know if you have any questions.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

   private JButton[][] buttons;

   public ButtonPane(int row, int col) {
      super(new GridLayout(row, col));
      buttons = new JButton[row][col];
      for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            final int curRow = i;
            final int curCol = j;
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton(i + ", " + j);
            buttons[i][j].addKeyListener(enter);
            buttons[i][j].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                  switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                  case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                     if (curRow > 0)
                        buttons[curRow - 1][curCol].requestFocus();
                     break;
                  case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                     if (curRow < buttons.length - 1)
                        buttons[curRow + 1][curCol].requestFocus();
                     break;
                  case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                     if (curCol > 0)
                        buttons[curRow][curCol - 1].requestFocus();
                     break;
                  case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                     if (curCol < buttons[curRow].length - 1)
                        buttons[curRow][curCol + 1].requestFocus();
                     break;
                  default:
                     break;
                  }
               }
            });
            add(buttons[i][j]);
         }
      }
   }

   private KeyListener enter = new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
         if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            ((JButton) e.getComponent()).doClick();
         }
      }
   };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.add(new ButtonPane(4, 4));
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

To run this, simply paste into a class called `ButtonPane`.

The important bit here is calling `requestFocus()` on the correct `JButton` when an arrow key is called.  I also registered an extra `KeyListener` for when the Enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard... Make sure you use

```
button.addActionListener(yourActionListener);
```

instead of creating a mouse listener.

Oh, I forgot the other part. :D

For browsing, you can use `button.requestFocus()` to change the focus to a specific button.

Here is some sample code:

```
final JButton matrix[][] = new JButton[4][4];
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y)
    {
        final int xx = x;
        final int yy = y;
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                int c = e.getKeyCode();
                if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                {
                    // Oops, corrected (xx > 0) to (yy > 0)
                    if (yy > 0) matrix[xx][yy-1].requestFocus();
                } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                {
                    if (yy < 3) matrix[xx][yy+1].requestFocus();
                }
                // Add the other directions here
            }
        });

        matrix[x][y] = b;
    }

}
```

Comment: But how do I browse among the buttons with arrows? up, down, left, right?

Comment: Does <enter> really work on your Java buttons?  I have addActionListener and <space> is the only thing that works.  Why would the behavior be different on my machine?

Comment: This is a LAF issue. On Windows, Enter will activate the button. On Metal you use the Space bar.

Comment: @camickr Thanks. I'm on Windows, but I'm using Nimbus.

Comment: I'm not sure what people think is wrong.  It looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

See [key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

```
component[0][0].getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT),
                        "moveRight");
component[0][0].getActionMap().put("moveRight", new Action() {
             @Override public void actionPerformed() {
                  component[0][1].requestFocus();
             }
});
```

I am not sure the code is quite right, but you get the idea.
You'll have to do 36 of those to get all the directions between all buttons,
so you'll probably want to write some loops to automate the process.

Comment: +1 for key bindings; you might be able to re-factor the mapping into the button creation, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797862/draw-a-line-in-a-jpanel-with-button-click-in-java/5797965#5797965).

Answer (score 2):

> how can I "click" on JButton by pressing ENTER instead of mouseclicking?

See [*Enter Key and Button*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/).

> How can I browse among the JButton with the arrows on keyboard instead of the mous

For the right/left arrow keys you can add these KeyStrokes to the focus traversal keys. See [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

For the up/down keys you will need to create a custom Action and then bind the Action to a KeyStroke. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). There is also a section in the tutorial on `How to Use Actions`.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the Focus Subsystem.**

This should get you started on using the arrow keys to select components. It is untested so pardon any errors :D

Assuming you have your button array in a JFrame,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//pseudo-method to add your buttons to the frame in the appropraite order.
frame.addButtonsToPanel(buttonArray, frame); 

//gets the default forward traversal keys (tab)
Set forwardKeys = frame.getFocusTraversalKeys(
KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS); 

// your own set of forward traversal keys
Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys); 

// add the RIGHT ARROW key 
newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0)); 

//apply your  new set of keys
frame.setFocusTraversalKeys(
KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, 
    newForwardKeys); 

//gets the default backward traversal keys (shift-tab)
Set backwardKeys = frame.getFocusTraversalKeys(
KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS); 

// your own set of backward traversal keys
Set newBackwardKeys = new HashSet(backwardKeys); 

// add the LEFT ARROW key 
newBackwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0)); 

//apply your  new set of keys
frame.setFocusTraversalKeys(
KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, 
    newBackwardKeys);
```

p.s See [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for more details

Comment: Yes, original reference is now included.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this little gem into my GUI utilities class recently. It simply adds new keys to the same system that does the [tab] focus changing:

```
public static void addUpDownToTraversalKeys(Component c)
{   
    addTraversalKeys(c, KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    addTraversalKeys(c, KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyEvent.VK_UP);
}

public static void addLeftRightToTraversalKeys(Component c)
{   
    addTraversalKeys(c, KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    addTraversalKeys(c, KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
}

public static void addTraversalKeys(Component c, int keysetId, int...keyCodes)
{   
    HashSet<AWTKeyStroke> newKeys = 
        new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>(
                c.getFocusTraversalKeys(keysetId));
    for (int keyCode : keyCodes)
        newKeys.add(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(keyCode, 0));
    c.setFocusTraversalKeys(keysetId,newKeys);
}
```

Added to my GuiUtilities class, a simply call to `GuiUtilities.addUpDownToTraversalKeys(this);` inside the frame's constructor allows using the up and down arrow keys to go through all elements. Note that `addLeftRightToTraversalKeys()` is not advised if you got text areas ;)