# i cant use left and right key on Jtextfield to move cursor

Tags: java, jtextfield

Hi i have  a problem ,

i Cant use left and right key on Jtextfield to move cursor

When I want to change a sentence on Jtextfield it does not give me the hand to use left and right Keys

```
 jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jPanel1);
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
    textField2 = new java.awt.TextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setAutoscrolls(false);
    jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1500, 1500));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2000, 2000));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    jScrollPane2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    jScrollPane2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(3000, 3000));
    jScrollPane2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(3000, 3000));

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    textField1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    textField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.add(textField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 130, 2260, 70));
```

Thank you

Comment: Mix of swing and awt - `textField1 = new java.awt.TextField()`. Use JTextField instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer that when you move the mouse pointer through the JTextField, you cannot see this pointer changing to "text select" mode. I think that you have to change the Cursor to `textField1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));`

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi sorry this command doesnt work they  just give me a hand on cursor,

Comment: what i need is can use left and right button on keyboard

Comment: I am sorry, I miss understood. To browse through the different components, Swing uses Tab key by default, otherwise you should set some listeners in order to manage what you want with the keys that you prefer. This link may give you some ideas about it: [Browse through JButtons using arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065959/browsing-jbuttons-with-arrow-keys). Good luck :)