# Control points of the edge moving

Tags: java, swing, graph, points

In my graph edges have points and I want to have such behavior: I drag one of edges points another points stay in place and only my point(under mouse cursor) is dragging and the distance between another points changes. How can I implement this?

Comment: you have to change your Point definitions in the Line 87.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, please.

Comment: Yes, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), you might look at these examples for some ideas: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) shows how to manipulate a line with two endpoints. [This more complex example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) manages a `List<Node>` in which each node represents a `Point` that can be dragged.