# KeyListener is unresponsive 1st time used?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, runnable

I looked at these links, none helped me. Im making a game with a JFrame using KeyListener and Runnalbe. I've never had a problem with it in games i have made in the past, but now heres  what im talking about:

- i start my program and the window comes up, message displays everything looks fine.
- no keys work
  -i close the window
  -The 2nd time its opened everything works fine. 
  -If i reset the virtual machine and try again, back to square 1.

here is my constructor:

```
public Game()
{
    super("ZMan");
    addKeyListener(this);
    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);


    i = createImage(800,600);
    b = i.getGraphics();
    makeLevel();
    souls = new Image[3];
    particles = new double[20][3];
    pc = 10;
    pH = 20;
    player = new Image[8];
    nme = new Image[8];
    showMessage = false;
    try
    {
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.png"));
        abg = ImageIO.read(new File("abg.png"));
        bil = ImageIO.read(new File("buildingP.png"));
        bilP = ImageIO.read(new File("building.png"));
        message = ImageIO.read(new File("./system/messageBG.png"));

        souls[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("sR.png"));
        souls[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("sG.png"));
        souls[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("sB.png"));
        rem = souls[0];
        //player
        player[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/normal.png"));
        player[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pBloop.png"));
        player[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pscorp.png"));
        player[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pSqui.png"));
        player[4] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pCato.png"));
        player[5] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pChubs.png"));
        player[6] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pPluckers.png"));
        player[7] = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/pSpooky.png"));
        gate = ImageIO.read(new File("./gate.png"));
        levelUp = ImageIO.read(new File("./system/levelUp.png"));
        xL = ImageIO.read(new File("./player/x.png"));
        /*
        nme[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("./enemies/bloop.png"));
        nme[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("./enemies/bloop.png"));
        nme[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("./enemies/scorp.png"));
        nme[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("./enemies/squi.png"));
        nme[4] = ImageIO.read(new File("./enemies/cato.png"));
         */
        nme[0] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/bloob.png");
        nme[1] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/bloob.png");
        nme[2] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/scorp.png");
        nme[3] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/squi.png");
        nme[4] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/cato.png");
        nme[5] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/chubs.png");
        nme[6] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/pluckers.png");
        nme[7] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("./enemies/spooky.png");
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    powerT = new String[8];
    powerT[0] = "You went back to normal";
    powerT[1] = "You are now Bloop!";
    powerT[2] = "You are now Scorp!";
    powerT[3] = "You are now Squi!";
    powerT[4] = "You are now Cato!";
    powerT[5] = "You are now Chubs!";
    powerT[6] = "You are now Pluckers";
    powerT[7] = "You are now Spooky";
    startAim();
    //music = new Music("./system/music/0.wav");
    t.start();
}
```

does nyone know the problem?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't agree that 73 lines of code is 'a lot of code'., but +1 for the idea of posting an SSCCE.  And to Erik when preparing an SSCCE: 1) Either hot-link to images on the net or generate them in code.  2) Reduce all arrays (`souls`, `player`, `nme`, `powerT` etc.) to contain just 2 elements.

Comment: well yes but i just included them so i can see if they may change anything at all (probably not)

Comment: Its odd i actually found out that i have to wait a minute until it worked. but that still shouldn't happen. Its an obscure amount of time for only 570 lines of code in the entire game!

Answer (score 3):

"To fire keyboard events, a component must have the keyboard focus."—[*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). I'm guessing the relevant component has focus the second time. You can try [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) or, preferably, look at [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Addendum: There's a key binding example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Comment: key bindings wouldnt help. I've tried. and the focus is not the problem. i added that line of code to it did do anything different

Comment: I've added a link above on how to use `requestFocusInWindow()`; look for "to ensure that a particular component gains the focus the first time a window is activated."

Comment: yes and that's how i have it. right before it the setVisible(true)

Comment: What is the `boolean` result of your invocation of `requestFocusInWindow()`?

Comment: Also, verify that you are using the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: it says false. very odd. no matter where i put it it says false.

Comment: Verify the result of `isFocusable()`; I presume your already `setFocusable(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound dumb, but it's more of a sanity check. Check your main method. I'd recommend doing a debug stepthrough, making sure that the first time the window is launched, the constructor to Game is actually called...Nothing about the constructor appears to be bad (to me), which makes me think that the instantiation of the object might be hosed.

If it isn't that, I can't help you; you'll have to wait for someone smarter in the specifics of your problem to answer :)

Comment: it is called because if it wasnt then none of the images would appear on screen.