# JTable enter key

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing an application using `jTable` for inventory management.

The action is, by typing the item code in a `jTextField` and by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the details of that code should come to `jTable`. And there I have to type the quantity and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to calculate the amount. But now by giving item code the details come to the `jTable`, and I can type the quantity, but there by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key `jTable` focus goes to the next row and no calculation is being done. But by again pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the `jTextField` the last entered amount is getting calculated. I don't know how to solve this problem as I am a beginner in Java. I am using MySQL and Java in Netbeans.

I am giving that code below..

Thank You..

```
jTable1.editCellAt(serialNumber, 2);
jTable1.getCellSelectionEnabled();

value1 = new Double(jTable1.getValueAt(serialNumber, 2).toString());
value = new Double(jTable1.getValueAt(serialNumber, 3).toString());
double result = value1 * value;

jTable1.setValueAt(result, serialNumber, 4);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default [*Key Binding*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the `selectNextRowCell` action in the table's `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` input map. You can substitute your own action, as outlined below.

```
private static final String solve = "Solve";
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(enter, solve);
table.getActionMap().put(solve, new EnterAction());
...
private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

See also [*Keyboard Bindings in Swing*](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626114430/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html) (mirrored at web.archive.org).

Addendum: You can find more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513), [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel) and [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/); the last one is `JTable` specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But i dont know much about key binding..If you dont mind can you please tell me where or how i have to add this code step by step..i am totally confused..

Comment: Yes, it's a little confusing at first. I found it helpful to read the tutorials and try a few examples; more above.

Comment: Excellent. Don't hesitate to update your question or pose a new one containing your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) as the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 lambda functions:

```
final String tustakmaad = "Solve";
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        panel.getTblBelgetarihiliste().getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
            enter, tustakmaad);
        panel.getTblBelgetarihiliste().getActionMap().put(tustakmaad, new DelegateAction(
            ae -> eventMytable_enterkey()));
```

and `DelegateAction` class should be like this:

```
package com.ozpas.entegre.controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

public class DelegateAction extends AbstractAction {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ActionListener myaction = (ae) -> {
        System.out.println("empty action");
    };

    public DelegateAction(ActionListener customaction) {
        this.myaction = customaction;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myaction.actionPerformed(e);
    }

    public ActionListener getMyaction() {
        return myaction;
    }

    public void setMyaction(ActionListener myaction) {
        this.myaction = myaction;
    }

}
```