# Adding a KeyListener to JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, double-click, keylistener, tablecelleditor

I have added a `KeyListener` to `JTable`; but when I double click on a table cell, the `KeyListener` stops working.

```
public class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        char i = ke.getKeyChar();
        int ib = ((int) i);
        if ((ib == 8)) {
            if (jt1.isEditing()) {
                jt1.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
            }
        } else {
            // my code to do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `KeyListener`; use a [*Key Binding*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). More examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095442/230513).

Alternatively, implement a custom table cell editor, as shown in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Maybe in this situation Key Binding is ok. But if you want to perform simple action on your table, for example on arrow keys, it's easy to use KeyListener. And solve all incoming problems by JTable.requestFocusInWindow(). I spend 1h on this Bindings thing and simple KeyListener solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your down-vote. I empathize, but I must disagree.

Answer (score -1):

use MouseListener ...

```
jt1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)  
            {  
                if (evt.getClickCount() == 2)
                {
                    jt1.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
                                }
                         }
                  });
```

try the same for adding keyListener...  in clickcount..