# Java: JLayeredPane and Lines or Circles

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, jlayeredpane

I have the following Problem:
I have a JLayeredPane and I need to add a Circle and some Lines to it. The Problem wit the Lines is, that they should be able to be redrawn/to move position (The Lines Symbolize some moving Vectors)
When I just add some GLines to the Graphics JLayeredPane.getGraphics() they are permanent. Or is there any possibility to Redraw the JLayeredPane.getGraphics()?

Please Help!

Comment: What is a 'GLines'?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LinePanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) shows one approach, but it can be adapted to any [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). For many lines, your program might maintain a `List<Shape>`. In any case the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) may serve as a foundation for your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).