# Java moving a circle in a gui with arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics2d, keyevent

I am trying to move a circle left with a keyEvent.  So far, the circle is drawn on the window but it does not move left!  I feel like the problem is where I add the Window() constructor to the container.  The is no output on the console to tell me that it is working.  So I dont think it even reaches the KeyEvent class.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Window extends JPanel {

    private static Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    public Window() {
        super();
        int width = 400;
        int height = 400;
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0.5 * width, 0.9 * height,
                0.1 * width, 0.05 * height);
        addKeyListener(new MoveCircle());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D brush = (Graphics2D) g;
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        brush.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        brush.draw(circle);
    }

    public class MoveCircle implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Working on top!");
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("Working on bottom!");
                circle.x++;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.add(new Window());
        frame.addKeyEvent(window.new MoveCircle());
        frame.setSize(800, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what is happening is this, you are adding `Window` to the `JFrame`, but the focus lies with the `JFrame`, so when you type on your `Keyboard` that thing goes to the `JFrame` not the `KeyListener` attached to the `Window` class. So in order to get over it, you simply have to call `requestFocusInWindow()` on the `Window` class's Object. Try this code, I had done some modification regarding EDT and stuff.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Window extends JPanel {

    private static Ellipse2D.Double circle;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Window() {
        super();
        int width = 400;
        int height = 400;
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0.5 * width, 0.9 * height,
                0.1 * width, 0.05 * height);        
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D brush = (Graphics2D) g;
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        brush.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        brush.draw(circle);
    }

    public class MoveCircle implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Working on top!");
            if (e.getKeyCode() == Event.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Working on bottom!");
                double newX = circle.x - 1;
                circle.x = newX;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGUI(Window window)
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();       
        container.add(window);
        window.addKeyListener(new MoveCircle());        
        frame.setSize(800, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        window.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.createAndDisplayGUI(window);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified it to work correctly now and the circle now moves left and right.  However I am trying to do somthing like newX = circle.x + 5.0;  This is doing nothing and the only way to get the circle to move is circle.x++;  I do not like how slow it moves...?

Comment: Had you tried using `circle.x += 5;` instead of `newX = circle.x + 5.0;` ?

Comment: Ah yes thank you.  I dont know why it wouldnt accept a new assignment.  Well you have saved the day and now I will continue with my game. Thank you sir!

Comment: Hehe, Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-) , the answer to this is when you writing `circle.x += 5;` you are incrementing the variable `x` of `circle`  object, else you have to write `circle.x = newX;` to make that thing work :-)

Comment: Good example; see also [`LinePanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) which uses key bindings to avoid the problem.

Comment: agree with @trashgod, lets KeyListener for whales, use KeyBindings

Comment: @trashgod : That example is really handy :-) , small drops can fill the Pitcher one day, this example did worked in that way for my knowledge. Thankyou for sharing that link :-)

Answer (score 1):

Only the focussed component will get key events. You need to call requestFocus() at some point.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be, to add the KeyListener to the JFrame. This way all the key strokes will throw an event, when the JFrame has the focus.

Comment: you mean frame.addKeyListeners(new MoveCircle()); in the main method?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, but this may not work, because MoveCircle() can only be called from Window. so my Solution is:`Window window = new Window();
container.add(window);
frame.addKeyListener(window.new MoveCircle());`

Comment: And are the System.out.prints(...); executed? Or is the console empty when pressing Enter on the JFrame?