# How can I find the enter location for KEY_TYPED event?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I've got a `KeyboardFocusManager` with overridden `dispatchKeyEvent()` method to handle navigation for arrow key and enter. I need to handle key events for as long as the key is pressed. Unfortunately, holding down enter results in `KEY_TYPED` events which do not contain the key location. Is there a way to find out which enter is currently being pressed? Or can I suppress `KEY_TYPED` events for enter in favour of `KEY_PRESSED` events?

edit:
I can't tell you the reason why it's done with a KeyboardFocusManager instead of KeyListeners but I'm sure there were reasons it was done this way. As of now, it is not possible anymore to change this. The problem is, that for our system(an old terminal emulator), the left enter key is a navigational key. Pressing enter moves the focus to the next textfield after the current line. The right enter key is a command key that sends the user input to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `KeyEventDemo` found in [*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe for either `KEY_PRESSED` or `KEY_RELEASED`. Of course, "[`KEY_TYPED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) events do not have a `keyLocation`."

It's not clear why you are using a [*Focus Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html), as many components already [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) certain keys to a defined [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) binds the arrow keys, which respond to auto-repeat events regulated by the host's preferences.

Comment: I can't tell you the reason why it's done with a KeyboardFocusManager instead of KeyListeners but I'm sure there were reasons it was done this way. As of now, it is not possible anymore to change this. The problem is, that for our system(an old terminal emulator), the left enter key is a navigational key. Pressing enter moves the focus to the next textfield after the current line. The right enter key is a command key that sends the user input to the server.
For some reasons, I only get one KEY_PRESSED event when holding enter.

Comment: Is it possible the `KeyboardFocusManager` was extended in order to stop auto-repeat events? You might look at the article [*Global Event Dispatching*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/) to see if it sheds any light.