# Duplicating JPanel Task

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, duplication

In java i have a panel and two buttons in it named b1 and b2. when i copy the panel and past it in the same frame, the button names become b3 and b4 but the code i wrote in the b1 doesn't shift to b3 ? how do i do this i.e. when creating a copy of the panel the code in b1 should be implemented in b3, also can it be done that suppose i have 'b2.doClick()' in the b1 actionperformed code turns to 'b4.doClick()' in b3 ActionPerformed when i duplicate the panel ? 
i am using netbeans(if this helps)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This looks something related to NetBeans GUI builder.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think that this is a code-related question. More of a *how do I do this in netbeans?*

Answer (score 1):

One way to get `b1` and `b3` to do the same thing is give each one the same [action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

```
JButton b1 = new JButton(new SomeAction());
JButton b3 = new JButton(new SomeAction());

class SomeAction extends AbstractAction {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
        // call some other action
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Action`; there's an example using `doClick()` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).