# Can't draw lines on existing panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, paintcomponent

I'm writing my first Java GUI with Swing.
I'm trying to create a panel with 10X10 dots and draw lines on these dots.

The problem is that I can create only one of the above.
Meaning that I can create a matrix of 10X10 dots or create lines.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("DrawMatrix");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawRectPanel());
        frame.setSize(240, 260);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawLine());
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

public class DrawRectPanel extends JPanel{
   final static int DIST = 20;
   final static int MAX_ROW = 11;
   final static int MAX_COL = 11;
   int i = 1;

@Override

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    {
        // Points matrix
        int x = 0;
        for(int row = 1; row < MAX_ROW; row++)
        {
             x = row * DIST;
            for(int col = 1; col < MAX_COL; col++)
            {
                int y = col * DIST;
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+1);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

public class DrawLine extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(20,20,40,40);
    }
 }
```

Any idea why? should I use setVisible in a different way?

Comment: See also [`LinePanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite each component added to the *contentPane* on successive calls to `add(..)`.

> I want both of them do be in the center, because i want to draw lines from point to point

You should rather use an approach which entails a single `DrawingPanel`, to which objects can be drawn to. You might also need an array(s) to hold the shapes to be drawn and so the can easily be got and manipulated `paintComponent(..)`.

- Please do remember to do all Swing component creation and manipulation on [Event Dispatch Thread via `SwingUtilities.inovkeLater(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- do not call `setSize()` on `JFrame` rather call `pack()` before setting `JFrame` visible rather override `getPrefferedSize` or `setPrefferedSize` of `JPanel` and return a dimension which fits all drawing in it.
- No need for `getContentPand.add(..)` simply call `add(..)` on `JFrame` as call will be directed to *contentPane*

Here is an example (basically you code with above fixes)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("DrawMatrix");
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    final static int DIST = 20;
    final static int MAX_ROW = 11;
    final static int MAX_COL = 11;
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Points matrix
        int x = 0;
        for (int row = 1; row < MAX_ROW; row++) {
            x = row * DIST;
            for (int col = 1; col < MAX_COL; col++) {
                int y = col * DIST;
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 1);
            }
        }
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 40, 40);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```