# How do I create an on screen keyboard in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on a school project where we have to create a virtual smartphone, to run on a computer.

My problem is that I need to create a keyboard on the screen (like on an smartphone), which you can then use by clicking with your mouse. I could just create every single `JButton`, but that will take a really long time. So I was hopping that someone knew some sort of algorithm that creates all the buttons and places them correctly on the screen.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: can you use html and javascript

Comment: That is one massive school project.

Comment: You could use a loop to simply the creation of all of those buttons.

Comment: nope we can only use java and write in Eclipse

Comment: yes I was thinking of a loop but cant figure out how... its a keyboard for writing text

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Swing-AWT/6311-virtual-onscreen-keyboard-project-using-java-and-swings.html

Comment: @NiklasJensen Create an array of your characters [a...z] and loop through generating buttons from that. Shouldn't be too hard assuming you want to keep the same dimension for each key.

Comment: thanks allot :D... I got it now :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp The assignment seems not to be for replicating other systems in order to develop apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could construct the buttons through the use of for loops.  One loop for every keyboard row is a plausible approach.

```
String row1 = "1234567890";
String row2 = "qwertyuiop";
// and so forth
String[] rows = { row1, row2, .. };
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    char[] keys = rows[i].toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; i < keys.length; j++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(Character.toString(keys[j]));
        // add button
    }
}
// add special buttons like space bar
```

This could be done more elegantly through a more OOP approach, but this basic loop system will work.

Comment: Can't say I am really pleased with the `setSize` call and the `setLocation` call

Comment: It's the least important part of the answer; can't say it necessitates a downvote.

Comment: An example which violates basic Swing principles, given to somebody who obviously is not yet very familiar with Java/Swing, deserves a downvote imo. Will remove my downvote now that that code is gone

Answer (score 7):

This simple example might help you:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField txt;
    private PopUpKeyboard keyboard;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        super("pop-up keyboard");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txt = new JTextField(20);
        keyboard = new PopUpKeyboard(txt);

        txt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Point p = txt.getLocationOnScreen();
                p.y += 30;
                keyboard.setLocation(p);
                keyboard.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(txt);

        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class PopUpKeyboard extends JDialog implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextField txt;

        public PopUpKeyboard(JTextField txt)
        {
            this.txt = txt;
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) createButton(Integer.toString(i));
            pack();
        }

        private void createButton(String label)
        {
            JButton btn = new JButton(label);
            btn.addActionListener(this);
            btn.setFocusPainted(false);
            btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            Font font = btn.getFont();
            float size = font.getSize() + 15.0f;
            btn.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));
            add(btn);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            txt.setText(txt.getText() + actionCommand);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 very nice although you might not want to extend `JFrame` class unless adding functionality, as this is considered bad practice.

Comment: +1 Also consider `Action` in preference to `ActionListener`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {

        myPanel.add(new JButton(alphabet.substring(i, i + 1)));
    }

    myFrame.add(myPanel);
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is a fast example of how to do it :).

Comment: This will only create one row of key buttons.  I don't know of any smartphones with their keyboards laid out like so.

Comment: that's exactly the point. This sample demonstrates the principle but at the same time it can't just be plugged into his assignment. I'm not going to do somebody's school assignment and allow them to get the credit for free.