# Call actionPerformed Method using normal method of class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to **call** the `actionPerformed()` in **normal method** of class. I know that it get automatically executed on whenever button get pressed. But I want to call that method when ENTER button get pressed on Specific **textfield**. Is it possible to call `actionPerformed()` in `keyPressed()` or in normal function/method.

The following code will give you rough idea what I want to do.

```
void myFunction()
{
      actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
      //my code
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you shouldn't do it if you want the execute method call then move your application logic to another method and call it processing events is a EDT job.

Comment: What's wrong with just letting the `ActionListener` do it's job?  This is the EXACT behaviour that `ActionListener` performs anyway

Answer (score 5):

If you want, some `actionPerformed()` method of a `JButton` to be executed on pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> inside a `JTextField`, then I guess you can use the [doClick()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29), method from `AbstractButton` class to achieve this. Though this approach, might can override the original behaviour of the `JTextField` on press of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key :(

Please have a look at this code pasted below, to see if this is what, stands fit for your needs :-) !!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonClickExample
{
    private JTextField tfield;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;

    private ActionListener actions = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (ae.getSource() == button)
            {
                label.setText(tfield.getText());
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == tfield)
            {
                button.doClick();
            }
        }
    }; 

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Click Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        tfield = new JTextField("", 10);
        button = new JButton("Click Me or not, YOUR WISH");
        tfield.addActionListener(actions);
        button.addActionListener(actions);
        centerPanel.add(tfield);
        centerPanel.add(button);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        label = new JLabel("Nothing to show yet", JLabel.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonClickExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `doClick()`, also seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) with key bindings.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but for other people seeing this my recomendation is something like this:

```
// This calls the method that you call in the listener method
void performActionPerformedMethod(){
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}

// This is what you want the listener method to do
void actionPerformedMethod(){
// Code...
}

// This is the interface method
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    actionPerformedMethod()
}
```

Comment: This one is no doubt, a good approach. More modular based, I like it +1 :-)