# How to create a "Pick Whip" (Adobe After Effects) in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, after-effects

In Adobe After Effects there is something called a "pick whip". It allows you to click on a dot on one object and drag a line from that dot to another element, making a connection between the two. I would like to duplicate this feature in my Java program using swing. I honestly have no idea where to start.

If I've done a bad job explaining what I mean, please comment so I can improve it. If there is some way outside of Swing to do this, I'm willing to try it.

Here are some examples of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`LinePanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) illustrates how to animate the line as it is rendered, but you'll have to paint on the [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) or among [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) instances to see the line above existing components.