# JTextField to int[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, parseint

I'm working on my graphic user interface for a application I'm creating. Basically there is this JTextField that the user has to input integers. For example

25, 50, 80, 90

Now, I have this other class that needs to get those values and put them in an int Array.

I've tried the following.

```
guiV = dropTheseText.getText().split(",");
```

And in the other class file I retieve the String, but I have no idea how to get the value for each one.

In the end I'm just trying to get something like

```
int[] vD = {textfieldvaluessplitbycommahere};
```

Still fairly new to Java but this has me crazy.

Comment: Create a method with the signature `int[] asInts(String[] data)`; this should hopefully show the task that needs to be done, `String[]` being the result of `String.split`. It would be called like: `int[] vD = asInts(str.split(","));`. Use `Integer.parseInt` to help inside this method. There are also libraries which can help here, but it'll be a "good exercise" to implement manually.

Comment: And this is why I *don't* use Java or languages without accepted/common use of HoFs :D

Comment: If these are coordinates, also consider graphical input, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private JTextField txtValues = new JTextField("25, 50, 80, 90"); 

// Strip the whitespaces using a regex since they will throw errors
// when converting to integers
String values = txtValues.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");

// Get the inserted values of the text field and use the comma as a separator.
// The values will be returned as a string array
private String[] strValues = values.split(",");

// Initialize int array
private int[] intValues = new int[strValues.length()];
// Convert each string value to an integer value and put it into the integer array
for(int i = 0; i < strValues.length(); i++) {
    try {
       intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(strValues[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       // The string does not contain a parsable integer.
    }

}
```

Comment: @DaftPunk Thanks for your remark. I stripped the whitespaces to prevent integers from being not parsable and caught the NumberFormatException as well. Wrote this code out of the blue

Comment: Keeps returning null for me? Did you exact steps. @StefHeylen

Comment: @StefHeylen I added .trim() and that seemed to solve it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are `fairly new to Java`, rather than giving you the code snippet, I will just give you some indications:

1. Use the String class: it has a method for splitting a String into an array of Strings.
2. Then use the Integer class: it has a method to convert a String to an int.

Comment: Yes (and the OP is already doing the first bit), but the problem is there is no trivial way to go `String[]->int[]` trivially in standard Java. (Writing a loop is easy, but not trivial - as in a single terse expression. Java lacks support for trivial "map" operations.)

Comment: I understand he is fairly new to Java but not to programming, so writing a loop is really a trivial issue. Likewise, I understand that giving some indications and forcing him/her to investigate is a better option.

Comment: Writing a loop is easy and tedious. Trivial is: `str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse)` (of course Java has no equivalent so ..) But take time to read the question; not just the title. This answer points out redundant information and doesn't even mention using a loop ..

Comment: Well, it's just that your concept of trivial is different to mine, but it's ok.

Comment: This is a great way to miss out on the accept when someone who isn't evasive and coy provides an answer with code and links to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it directly, you may need to add a method to convert your string array to int array. Something like this:

```
public int[] convertStringToIntArray(String strArray[]) {
    int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Pass your guiV to this method and get back the int array

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is a function hat does the conversion:

```
public static int[] convertTextFieldCommaSeparatedIntegerStringToIntArray(String fieldText) {
    String[] tmp = fieldText.split(",");
    int[] result = new int[tmp.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i].trim());
    }

    return result;
}
```

The essential methods are:

[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for splitting the original input at the comma.

[parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) for converting a String -> int. The [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) function of Integer is an option but then you have to convert String -> Integer -> int.

---

Note:

You should use [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to eliminate white-spaces. Furthermore, you should catch the [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) thrown by parseInt. As an unchecked exception you do not need to catch it, but it is always wise to check user input and sanitize it if necessary.

Comment: fsvo "simple" .. it is The Java Way though.

Comment: sadly yes, in most cases "simple" is quite verbose in java

Comment: I like this answer because it uses `trim()` - although the method name leaves something to be desired. I can't vote though. Also, adding links to the relevant method(s) would be nice.

Comment: I added a little more information and gave the function a more Java-ish name. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public int[] getAsIntArray(String str)
{
    String[] values = str.getText().split(",");
    int[] intValues = new int[values.length];
    for(int index = 0; index < values.length; index++)
    {
        intValues[index] = Integer.parseInt(values[index]);
    }
    return intValues;
}
```