# Using KeyListener to modify matrix

Tags: java, swing, matrix, jframe, keylistener

I have a mini project for java to do and I have some setbacks.

I want to pass the value of a keypress to my main class in order to call some methods that will move a certain value up,down,left or right inside a matrix, and then if possible paint a GUI based of the values inside that matrix.

Here is my class that returns the key code of the key I press inside a GUI.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Keys extends JFrame  implements KeyListener{
public static int keyVALUE;//I want to use this value inside another class
  public Keys()
   {
      addKeyListener( this ); 
   }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e);
   }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

 private  int displayInfo(KeyEvent e){


        int id = e.getID();
        if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
        } else {
             keyVALUE = e.getKeyCode();

            System.out.print(keyVALUE);

}
           return keyVALUE;}
}
```

My main class where I create and want to modify the matrix is this.

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;




 public class Matrix extends Keys {
public static int[][] Matrix = new int[9][9];


public void moveUp(){

}

public void moveDown(){

}
public void moveLeft(){

}
public void moveRight(){

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{      
             //since there is no GUI, here is a frame that picks up the key releases

             Keys keyPressed = new Keys();
         keyPressed.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
         keyPressed.setSize( 800, 600 ); // set frame size
         keyPressed.setVisible( true); // display frame 


         //set "car "2" and blocks "1" and paint GUI based on this
    for (int i = 0; i <9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            Matrix[i][j] = 0ș
            Matrix[4][4]=2;//start position

            System.out.print(Matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            }

        for(;;){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i <9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

        if(Matrix[i][j]==2 && Matrix[i-1][j]==0){

        Matrix[i-1][j]=2;
        Matrix[i][j]=0;
        Matrix[i][j]=Matrix[i-1][j];
        Matrix[i-1][j]=2;
        Matrix[i][j]=0;

        }}}


        for (int i = 0; i <9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

        System.out.print(Matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }

        if(Matrix[0][4]==2){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You               WON!","Winner",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);break;}
        if(Matrix[0][8]==2){break;}
        }
        }
 }
```

Any idea how I can do this ?
Is there any example of a program that resembles mine?

Thanks for the help and guidance!

Comment: Use *Key Bindings*, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).